# Looping a array in javascript - in an order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following loop in javascript array A

```
[
    {
    "key1": "value121212",
    "booleankey": false,
    },
    {
    "key1": "value143434",
    "booleankey": false,
    },
    {
    "key1": "value1454545",
    "booleankey": true,
    }
]
```

I need to loop the above array A and create another array B which includes `booleankey`,
Requirement is, when i create the new array B, the entry with `"booleankey": true,` should come first. Initial array A can have the booleankey as true as the last entry,

How can i make sure to get the new array B with booleankey true always on the first ?
This is how arrayB is created:

```
createArrayB(entry) {
    arrayA.map((entry) => {
            return  {
                newkey: entry.key1,
                newbooleankey: entry.booleankey,
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sort the array before you map over it? After you map over it?

Comment: as @jonrsharpe said, just sort it, and B is what you get as an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort by the boolean key with the delta of it. This moves all `true` property to top.

```js
var array = [{ key1: "value121212", booleankey: false }, { key1: "value143434", booleankey: false }, { key1: "value1454545", booleankey: true }];

array.sort((a, b) => b.booleankey - a.booleankey);

console.log(array);
```